# Is this free book, a good book for an introduction to complex analysis (self study)?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for a book about complex analysis. 
I found a free book that covers the material that I want.
http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnicafolder/lnica.html

However, before I spend hours in this book, I'm interested what you guys think of this book. If someone knows some complex analysis book, that covers roughly the same material, is of the same level, but is better, I'm willing to pay for such a book.

Maybe my question is a little bit vague, and I don't want to raise a large discussion why this book would be good or not.

I mostly intrested in finding books that cover roughly the same material and are of the same level. If you know such a book, I woud like to know. And I'm intrested why you think that is a good book.

Comment: It looks ok but it seems to lack some basic notions which one would expect to be covered in an introductory course: Weierstrass products, Mittag-Leffler theorem, Schwarz reflection principle, Phragmen-Lindelöf, .. But at least it does conformal mappings/Riemann mapping theorem.

Comment: @TooOldForMath I'm interested. What would you recommend as an introductory course that covers such topics? Mine didn't and I want to learn.

Comment: My personal favorite is Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*. That covers all these things and a lot more, but easier for a beginner is maybe Stein, Shakarchi *Complex Analysis* (Vol. 2 of a series on Real Analysis). They explain extremely well.

Comment: Fopr self-study it is usually best to check a few different sources. If you don't understand one, perhaps the other is clearer. And the other way around. Check out lecture notes on the 'web too.